# ObjectBox: Someone please clarify what happens with the disk space?

Tags: objectbox

I noticed that when I remove something using `obStore.remove(someObjects)` then the size of DB file does not change.  Here (https://docs.objectbox.io/faq#how-to-reclaim-disk-space-used-by-objectbox) it says `BoxStore.removeAllObjects()` does not reclaim disk space.  So the disk space that's not released gets reused when I put in new data?  The FAQ suggests calling `BoxStore.deleteAllFiles` to reclaim disk space.  Does that only releases the unused space and keep the valid data, or does it destroys the entire DB?  If it is the latter (as I presumed), is there a way to release only the unused space?

Answer (score 0):

The [FAQ entry](https://docs.objectbox.io/faq#how-does-objectbox-use-disk-space-and-can-i-reclaim-disk-space) has been updated to also cover the questions you are raising.

Most relevant sections for your questions:

> In most cases, ObjectBox uses disk space quite optimally. Only once
> you add more data, the database file grows as required. When you
> delete data, file areas are marked as unused internally and will be
> reused by ObjectBox. Note that re-using existing file areas is much
> more efficient than shrinking and growing the file. In practice, once
> used file storage will be used again in the future; especially
> considering that stored data has the tendency to get more over time.

and

> Non-standard use cases may require a temporary peak in data storage
> space that is followed by a permanent drop of storage space. To
> reclaim disk space for those cases, you need to delete the database
> files and restore them later [...]